# Makefile for Unit Tests in C++

Tags: c++, unit-testing, makefile

I'm struggling to write Makefiles that properly build my unit tests. As an example, suppose the file structure looks like this

```
src/foo.cpp
src/foo.hpp
src/main.cpp
tests/test_foo.cpp
tests/test_all.cpp
```

So, to build the executable test_all, I'd need to build test_foo.o which in turn depends on test_foo.cpp but also on src/foo.o.

What is the best practice in this case? One Makefile in the parent folder? One Makefile per folder? If so, how do I manage the dependencies across folders?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The common practice is one Makefile for each folder. Here is a simple *Makefile.am* script for the root folder:

```
#SUBDIRS = src tests
all:
    make -C ./src
    make -C ./tests    
install:
    make -C ./src install
uninstall:
    make -C ./src uninstall
clean:
    make -C ./src clean
test:
    make -C ./tests test
```

The corresponding *Makefile.am* for the *src* folder will look like this:

```
AM_CPPFLAGS = -I./

bin_PROGRAMS = progName

progName_SOURCES = foo.cpp main.cpp
LDADD = lib-to-link

progName_LDADD = ../libs/
```

*Makefile.am* for *tests* will look similar:

```
AM_CPPFLAGS = -I../src

bin_PROGRAMS = tests

tests_SOURCES = test_foo.cpp test_all.cpp
```

Use automake to generate *Makefile.in* files from the .am files. The *configure* script will use the .in files to produce the Makefiles. (For small projects you would like to directly hand-code the Makefiles).

Comment: This doesn't seem to take the dependency of test_all.cpp on src/foo.o into account. E.g. what happens after make clean; make test in the top level directory?

Comment: If the tests are driven from main.cpp, there won't be any dependency problems.

Comment: But main.cpp will be the executable of the application, not driving the tests. The executable conducting the tests should reside in the tests folder.

Comment: @Michael have you tried `tests_SOURCES = test_foo.cpp test_all.cpp ..\src\foo.cpp`? I gave an example so that you can easily pick up the rest :-)

Comment: Thanks Vijay, that was the last missing piece of the puzzle for me. I wasn't aware that dependencies across folders were handled correctly.

Answer (score 6):

Common practice is a Makefile per directory.  That's what I would have suggested before I read "Recursive Make Considered Harmfull" (http://miller.emu.id.au/pmiller/books/rmch/).  Now I'd recommend one Makefile.  Also check out the automatic dependency generation - now you don't even need to work out what your tests depends on.  All you need is some targets.

Comment: Thanks dave for the very interesting read. However, trying to really implement a non-recursive Makefile seems to be very complicated, as shown in http://www.xs4all.nl/~evbergen/nonrecursive-make.html -- This seems to be too much work for the small- to medium sized projects I'm involved in.

Comment: They do a lot more in that example than just have one Makefile.  I set up a top level Makefile reading their instructions with out all the bells and whistles in about 2 hours after reading that article (+ another 2-4 hours beforehand reading about make)

Comment: I wrote a single makefile for my whole project, and it's seriously not that complicated, but my project is just a single .c and .h file...

Comment: You can have multiple makefiles and **NOT** be recursive.  The difference is `make -C directory` vs `include directory/Makefile` in the top makefile.